# requiring loki inMemory database in server.js causes nodemon to constantly restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon, lokijs

[**Project repo**](https://github.com/leongaban/Getting-Started-with-Node.js)

After installed [lokijs](http://lokijs.org/) I created the following [database.js](https://github.com/leongaban/Getting-Started-with-Node.js/blob/master/app/database.js) file:

```
var loki = require('lokijs');

var db = new loki('db.json');

db.addCollection('top').insert([
    { term: 'JavaScript' , style : 'warning' },
    { term: 'Angular 2'  , style : 'danger'  },
    { term: 'NodeJS'     , style : 'success' },
    { term: 'REST'       , style : 'primary' }
]);

db.addCollection('searches');

db.saveDatabase();
```

---

As soon as I added `require('./database.js');` in my server.js file, nodemon is caught in a restart loop. `nodemon main`

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '../public/views');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));

require('./database.js');
require('./routes.js')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all the `json` files of lokijs in ignore array of **nodemon.json** like below

```
{
    "ignore": [
        "db1.json",
        "db2.json"
    ]
}
```

Now nodemon will not restart when you use `saveDatabase` function of lokijs

Answer (score 0):

Ah just realized I needed to ignore the db.json file, since that keeps getting overwritten.

`nodemon main.js --ignore db.json`

This will prevent the server restart loop.